# Pagination displaying issue php

Tags: php, html, pagination

In simple pagination, when clicking different no. `1,2,3,4,` records from table not changing
as they should. [image: Pagenation i created]
I'm displaying `5` records on each page,as on click `1` it display record from table `1` to `5`,and so on.But,it is not changing.Help me.

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("bluewater");

$page = $_GET["page"];
if($page=="" || $page=="1")
{
$page1=0;
}
else 
{
$page1=($page*5)-5;
}
$sql=mysql_query("select * from countries limit 1,5");

    while($ser = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) { 
    echo $ser["ccode"];
    echo $ser["country"];
    echo "<br>";
    }
$sql=mysql_query("select * from countries");
$cou=mysql_num_rows($sql);
$a=$cou/5;
$a= ceil ($a);
echo "<br>"; echo "<br>"; 
for ($b=1;$b<=$a;$b++)
{
?><a href="index.php?page=<?php echo $b; ?>" style="text-decoration:none"><?php echo $b." ";?></a> <?php
}
?>
```

Comment: `mysql_query("select * from countries limit 1,5");` - notice the `1`, it will always start from 1 this way ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1) Don't use **mysql_** functions, use [**mysqli_**](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli.php) or [**PDO**](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdostatement.php).

2) To move via pages, you need to increase offset in query.

```
$page = $_GET['page'];
$itemsPerPage = 5;
$offset = ($page * $itemsPerPage) - $itemsPerPage;

$query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `countries` LIMIT {$itemsPerPage} OFFSET {$offset}");
$query->execute();
$results = $query->fetchAll();
```

Comment: Can you suggest a best way to add next and previous option?I know many sites,but a specific way in any code,suppose in this only?

Comment: @125fura If you mean `previous` ant `next` buttons in pagination, than it's just links to `$page - 1` and `$page + 1`, like `example.com/index.php?page=5`/`example.com/index.php?page=7`

Answer (score 4):

You never make use of your `$page` variable in the query. Change it to

`select * from countries limit ".$page.", 5`

and it should work

Also, `mysql_real_escape_string($page)`!

Comment: where i should apply this,in 2nd query or in first?

Comment: No, no, no, no, no, no, no, no. Please go through every word in `mysql_real_escape_string(..)`, imagine what the function does and then tell me why it is wrong to use it here.

Comment: So you are advising against escaping a $_GET parameter? You live a very dangerous life... of course, `$page = intval($_GET['page'])` would be more appropriate... but in the original version, it is sure to give you SQL injection headaches.

Answer (score 2):

```
$sql=mysql_query("select * from countries limit $page1,5");
```

replace the first query with above code.

Answer (score 1):

Just  replace the  your  first  sql query  with the my sql query:

your sql query
$sql=mysql_query("select * from countries limit 1,5");

You provided static start limit is "1"

Correct Sql query:
$sql=mysql_query("select * from countries limit $page1,5");

Make its static limit is $page1 variable.

Answer (score -1):

Try this approach.It is easier to understand.

//code for database connection

$left_rec=$rec_count-($page*$rec_limit);
$res=mysqli_query("select * from countries");
$rec_count=mysqli_num_rows($res);//Total no of records
 
if(isset($_GET['page']))
{
     $page=$_GET['page']+1;
     $offset=$rec_limit*$page;
}
else
{
    $page=0;
 
    $offset=0;
}
$rec_limit=5;//no of records per page 
$offset=$page*$rec_limit;
$left_rec=$rec_count-($page*$rec_limit);
$res=mysqli_query("select * from countries limit $offset,$rec_limit");
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) 
 { 
    echo $row["ccode"];
    echo $row["country"];
    echo "
";
 }
if($page==0)
{ 
     echo"Next";
}
else if($left_rec <= $rec_limit)
{
     $last=$page-2;
     echo"Prev";
}
?>